# How to use Fused Location Provider client in android lollipop

Tags: android, geolocation, location, android-gps, fusedlocationproviderclient

I'm trying to get my current location to show it on map using "FusedLocationProviderClient"
but it is not working in android lollipop although it is working fine in all above versions. Below is code sample what I'm trying to do.

```
        if (checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return v;
        }
        fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                mLastLocation=location;

                getAltitude();
                if(mMap!=null){

                    if(location!=null){
                        Marker marker=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude())));
                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()),15.0f));
                    }
                    }
            }
        });
```

Comment: What is the error in lollipop version??

Comment: Have you give all necessary permissions ?

Comment: Yes. all permissions are granted properly .no error just show null location in onsuccess method.